# Using HttpEntity and HttpHeaders to connect to SalesForce

Tags: json, spring, rest, http-headers, salesforce

I'm completely new at this, so forgive me if this question seems really basic.

I'm following this guide: https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.datadotcom_api_dev_guide.meta/datadotcom_api_dev_guide/quickstart_connectwithoauth.htm

And I want to get a access token, but I keep getting 400 bad request. What am I doing wrong here?

```
String uri = "https://na1.salesforce.com/services/oauth2/token";

HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
headers.setContentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON);
headers.set("client_id", "some_id");
headers.set("client_secret", "secret_thing");
headers.set("grant_type", "password");
headers.set("username", "username@foo.com");
headers.set("password", "password_here");

HttpEntity<String> request = new HttpEntity<String> (headers);

System.out.println(new RestTemplate().exchange(uri, HttpMethod.GET,request, Object.class));
```

What's wrong with the above code? I keep getting a 400 bad request instead of a json blob, which is really what I want.

Here is the error I keep getting:

```
 15/03/22 12:55:35 WARN client.RestTemplate: GET request for "https://na1.salesforce.com/services/oauth2/token" resulted in 400 (Bad Request); invoking error handler

org.springframework.web.client.HttpClientErrorException: 400 Bad Request
    at org.springframework.web.client.DefaultResponseErrorHandler.handleError(DefaultResponseErrorHandler.java:88)
    at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.handleResponseError(RestTemplate.java:532)
    at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.doExecute(RestTemplate.java:488)
    at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.execute(RestTemplate.java:446)
    at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.exchange(RestTemplate.java:393)
```

Comment: Why are you setting the content type of the request to JSON?

Comment: I don't know? I mean, the response kinda looked like JSON. What should it be?

Comment: Let me emphasize one part of my previous question: Why are you setting the content type of the **request**?

Comment: No real clue. I was just trying out what people posted online, and what others told me to do at my work. The code I posted can be completely wrong.

Comment: Is your secret correctly formatted? Are the rest of the headers?

Comment: To be clear, can someone tell me what I'm doing wrong, and what I should be doing? I'm having trouble googling for solutions; nothing I find is exactly what I'm trying to do.

Comment: I think so. I mean, am I supposed to be doing anything special? I'm not doing any sort of encoding; the example online doesn't say as much (The salesforce link in my original post.)

Comment: If I try the curl request, I get a 400 with `invalid_client_id` in the response body. Try your request with `curl` and make it verbose `-v`.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/73538/discussion-between-user1116858-and-sotirios-delimanolis).